# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input with CORS HTTP post request

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am trying to issue HTTP post request via fetch API:

```
const loginUser = () => {
    const name = (document.getElementById("email")  as HTMLInputElement).value;
    const password = ( document.getElementById("password")  as HTMLInputElement).value;

    fetch('http://localhost:8080/auth/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        mode:'cors',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: name,
            password: password
        })
    }).then(response => { console.log(response.text); console.log(response);response.json()})
        .then(json => console.log(json))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

However the response is:

```
ƒ text() { [native code] }
Login.tsx:18 Response {type: 'cors', url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth/login', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}body: (...)bodyUsed: trueheaders: Headers {}[[Prototype]]: Headersok: trueredirected: falsestatus: 200statusText: ""type: "cors"url: "http://localhost:8080/auth/login"[[Prototype]]: Response
Login.tsx:18 undefined
VM5958:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

As you can see, the request is 'ok', yet the json parsing results in `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` error. Why  is this happening?

On my server side i return:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, jwtToken);
headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json");

return ResponseEntity
        .ok()
        .headers(headers)
        .build();
```

Why is this happening? Is Cors somehow blocking json parsing? THanks for help!

Comment: We'll need to see the actual response body. Also, `response.text` is not a string, it's an async method, just like `response.json()`.

Comment: The reason your second `.then` is receiving `undefined` is that your first `.then` function has no return value. You probably want to `return response.json()`. And note that you _cannot_ call `response.json()` after calling `response.text()` -- a Response instance will only let you read its body one time. My advice is to read it as text (so you can log it for debugging purposes), and then parse it as JSON in the second `.then`.

Comment: @tom tried it, result error is the same

Answer (score 1):

### Response bodies can only be read one time

Your question is: why am I receiving "Unexpected end of JSON input"?

The answer is: either because you are reading the body once beforehand, or because the body is actually empty.

You can either read the body as text, like so: `let bodyTextPromise = response.text()`, or you can read it as JSON, like so: `let bodyDataPromise = response.json()`. Both methods cause the response to mark its body as "read," which then makes any subsequent attempt to read it fail.

The other problem you're facing is that your first success handler is discarding all the data that comes from the server, because it does not return anything.

Let's look at your first success handler:

```js
.then(response => {
  console.log(response.text) 
  console.log(response)
  response.json()
})
```

The first `console.log` is **worthless**. `response.text` is a native method that returns a promise. It *is not* the raw body text. That's why your log has this line:

```
ƒ text() { [native code] }
```

The second `console.log` shows you that the body is being read -- that's what is meant by `bodyUsed: true` in the output. However, this can be misleading, because when you log real objects in a browser's JS console, those instances will update to reflect changes to the object made by subsequent code. So, I think `bodyUsed` is actually *false* when that log runs, but then becomes true on the next line when you call `response.json()`.

Now let's look at your second success handler:

```js
.then(json => {
  console.log(json)
})
```

You expect this handler to receive data, but it will not! The reason is that chained `.then` functions receive whatever the previous function returned. Since the first success handler has no `return` statement, this second handler will receive no arguments at all, and `json` will be undefined.

Here's the code you really want:

```js
.then(response => response.text())
.then(text => {
  console.log(`response text`, text)
  return JSON.parse(text)
})
.catch(console.error)
```

If that code still throws an error, you can study the actual response text to see why it fails parsing.

Comment: you are probably right, the body seem to be empty. However i cannot even read headers

Comment: You should study the exchange in your browser's Network panel. If CORS is the problem, it will tell you.

Comment: Also note that `loginUser` has no return.

Comment: @Tom the network tab show request with all headers, yet when i try to read the headers from fetch response i get null

Comment: I don't see any code in your post where you try to access the response headers, and the question you asked was about parsing the response body as JSON. If you have a problem with headers, you should [do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=fetch+response+headers), and if you can't make sense of the docs, post a second question focused on how to access response headers.